# Model name same as another model(user) column name same in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The model name (Contact) same as anther model(user) column name (contact) same
example:

```
User.first
#<User id: 2, username: "xyz", created_at: "2020-08-21 12:36:10", updated_at: "2021-12-04 16:10:29", email: "xyz@gmail.com", is_active: true, job_title: nil, defualt_role: "Super Admin", **contact**: "9900855603">

Contact.first
=> nil
```

I need to find out user contact

query is:

```
User.first.contact
showing nil
=> nil
```

please help on this.

Comment: What is the code for the Contact model?

Comment: `User.first[:contact]` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D

Answer (score 0):

Either you define a 1:N relation between user and contact (User has many Contacts) or differentiate the model reference name

1:N solution
on user.rb

```
has_many :contacts
```

1:1 solution
on user.rb

```
has_one :user_contact, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: :Contact
```